# Parsing JSON With No Tag F#

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, f#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON:

```
    {  
   "-L3ELSSzZPRdjCRcFTrb":{  
      "senderId":"SWs56OIGzMdiCjSXahzDQX8zve92",
      "senderName":"alberto",
      "text":"Hi"
   },
   "-L3EN1NW5hHWBTEGC9ve":{  
      "senderId":"YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2",
      "senderName":"David",
      "text":"Hey"
   }
}
```

To do so I have created the following two records:

```
type MessageContent = 
{ senderId: string
  senderName: string
  text: string; }

type Messages = 
    {
        messages_list : Map<string,MessageContent>;
    }
```

Next, I call:

```
let messages_json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Types.Messages>(html)
```

however, this produces the following result:

```
{{messages_list = null;}}
```

The problem seems to be that there is no `messages_list` tag in the JSON, so the converter cannot find this tag and returns null. How would I handle a jSON like this though where no initial tag is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is probably by using the `[<JsonExtensionData>]` attribute and adding `[<CLIMutable>]`

Change your Messages type like this (you might also have to add `[<CLIMutable>]` to your `MessageContent` type)

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Messages = { [<JsonExtensionData>] messages : IDictionary<string, JToken> }
```

Then you can deserialize it into a map like this

```
let msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Messages>(html)
let messagemap = 
    msg.messages 
    |> Seq.map (fun kvp -> kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToObject<MessageContent>())
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

which will leave you with a map of `MessageContent` records.